# How can I get my laptop working?

Tags: asus-laptop, laptop-repair

I was cleaning my laptop with a little bit of soapy water on a cloth. Normally I use a very little bit but I used a bit much and a very small amount went down the vent running along the top of the keyboard and some went down into the keyboard itself.

Because it was such a small amount of water, I foolishly dried everything off that I could, plugged it in and turned it on. It booted to the Windows login screen fine but the keyboard didn't work. It then switched off after about 15 seconds. Tried again with the same result.

I then opened it up, unplugged it and removed the battery. Left it for 20 hours or so, put it all back together and tried again. Now the power button sometimes works and sometimes doesn't but the laptop switches itself off after a few seconds max (power light goes off). Sometimes the screen lights up with Windows attempting to automatically repair the OS (presumably because it's been forcibly switched on and off so much) and sometimes it doesn't. The screen always cuts to black when the power light goes off.

Just to exacerbate things, I slightly mangled the battery connector on the motherboard while taking out the battery in a panic. As far as I can tell, the pins of the connector are seated properly on the connector on the battery itself but some of the supporting plastic/metal bits are bent/broken.

My laptop is an ASUS Vivobook S14. Is there any hope for repair?

Comment: You did just about every wrong thing you could, I'm afraid. It needs a professional now. see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275 for a cautionary tale.

Comment: Thank you. Ironically, I knew almost all of this except the "leaving it to dry causes more damage" but assumed because it was such a tiny amount, it'd be OK - I realise how silly that was now!

Comment: Is there hope for professional repair or should I just get a new one?

Comment: You'll only discover that once the professional has looked at it ;)